# isalnum not showing correctly because of linebreaks

Tags: python-3.x, line-breaks

I have a file called strings.txt. I need to use `isalmun()` to see if the line has special characters or not.

my code so far:

```
file = open('strings.txt', 'r')

while True:
    next_line = file.readline()

    if not next_line:
        break;
    print(next_line.strip(),next_line.isalnum())

file.close()
```

But it doesn't give right results because each line has a linebreak `\n` which makes a proper line fail, output:

```
5345m345Ć¶34l False
no2no123non4 False
noq234n5ioqw#% False
%#""SGMSGSER False
```

The second line should be `True`.
Code below shows that each line has `\n`

```
# -*- coding: UTF8 -*-


readfile = open("strings.txt","r")
content = readfile.readlines()

print(content)
for i in content:
    print(i)

readfile.close()
```

Output:

```
['5345m345Ć¶34l\n', 'no2no123non4\n', 'noq234n5ioqw#%\n', '%#""SGMSGSER\n', 'doghdp5234\n', 'sg,dermoepm\n', '43453-frgsd\n', 'hsth()))\n', 'bmepm35wae\n', 'vmopaem2234+0+\n', 'gsdm12313\n', 'bbrbwb55be3"?"#?\n', '"?"#%#"!%#"&"?%%"?#?#"?"\n', 'retrte#%#?%\n', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxy']
5345m345Ć¶34l
```

How do I ignore the linebreak `\n`? I can't just join the lines or replace the linebreak because I need them to be as they are now, not as 1 single long line. Also I'm trying to figure out how to rename `False` and `True` to something else. I was able to rename them but only by printing the results in a new line instead of behind the existing lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice the string you are reading by 1 if they all end with a \n
`next_line[:-1]` then you can evaluate if it's `alnum()`

Answer (score 0):

I used strip for this task after reading the line:

```
rivi_1 = rivi_1.strip('\n')
```